# Как синхронизировать работу потока и основной программы, чтобы они не мешали друг другу?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

После нажатия кнопки поток отключает доступ к программе, я не могу даже выйти из программы.Что мне делать. в listView1 должны пробежаться строки a, b, c, d и при этом я должен делать что либо с с основной формой. Например набирать текст в textbox. Как синхронизировать работу потока и основной программы, чтобы они не мешали друг другу.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread childThread = new Thread(getlistAsync);
    childThread.Start();
}

private void getlistAsync()
{
    while (true)
    {
        add("a", "b", "c", "d");
    }
}

public async Task add(string prob, string reg, string data, string user)
{
    String[] row = { prob, reg, data, user };

    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row);

    this.listView1.BeginInvoke(
    new Action(() =>
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
        listView1.Refresh();
    }));
}

private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.Columns.Add("Problems", 80);
    listView1.Columns.Add("Data", 120);
    listView1.Columns.Add("Registry Key", 130);
    listView1.Columns.Add("users", 80);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

От того, что вы убрали в отдельный поток заполнение контрола, никакой пользы не будет, т.к. ваш бесконечный цикл будет постоянно дергать UI-поток, чтобы обновить отображение контрола, что собственно и приводит к ожидаемому зависанию, да еще и накладным расходам на межпоточное взаимодействие.

Можете провести эксперимент и убедиться в этом, добавив в ваш цикл, который бежит в отдельном потоке `Thread.Sleep(1000)`.

Не знаю какую реальную задачу вы пытаетесь решить таким способом, но в отдельный поток стоит стоит выносить операции, которые выполняются долго и не дергают UI-постоянно.

Answer (score 1):

Из того, что я вижу - это WinForms, а там все трудозатратные задачи требуется выполнять в фоновом потоке, BackgroundWorker. Обратите внимание на эту [статью](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-implement-a-form-that-uses-a-background-operation)